# building login api backend functionality with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I have react app is making calls to ruby on rails. I'm building login page i got stuck on the password authenticate part. getting error

```
 "#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)>"
```

the error is happening on this line

```
  if user && user.authenticate(password)
```

here is from the comman line 
[image]

this is users_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:logout]

def facebook
 enter code hereif params[:facebook_access_token]
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:facebook_access_token])
  user_data = graph.get_object("me?fields=name,email,id,picture")

  user = User.find_by(email: user_data['email'])
  if user
    user.generate_authentication_token
    user.save
    render json: user, status: :ok
  else
    user = User.new(
                fullname: user_data['fullname'],
                email: user_data['email'],
                uid: user_data['id'],
                provider: 'Facebook',
                image: user_data['picture']['data']['url']
            )
    user.generate_authentication_token

    if user.save
      render json: user, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: user.errors, is_success: false}, status: 422
    end
  end
  else
  render json: { error: "Invalid Facebook Token", is_success: false}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def logout
 user = User.find_by(access_token: params[:access_token])
 user.generate_authentication_token
 user.save
 render json: { is_success: true}, status: :ok
end

def login
 email = user_params[:email]
 password = user_params[:password]
 user = User.find_by(email: email)
 if user && user.authenticate(password)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render json: user, status: :ok
 else
 render json: { error: user.errors, is_success: false}, status: 422
 end
end

def add_card
user = User.find(current_user.id)
if user.stripe_id.blank?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    email: user.email
  )
  user.stripe_id = customer.id
  user.save
else
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_id)
end

customer.sources.create(source: params[:stripe_token])
render json: { is_success: true}, status: :ok
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
render json: { error: e.message, is_success: false}, status: :not_found
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
end

end
```

here is routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
namespace :api, defautls: {format: :json} do
namespace :v1 do
  get '/logout' => 'users#logout'
  get '/login' => 'users#login'
  post '/login' => 'users#login'
  post '/signup' => 'users#signup'
  end
 end
end
```

here is user.rb model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_secure_password
 before_create :generate_authentication_token
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
 :validatable,
     :confirmable, :omniauthable
 validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 
 50}
end
def generate_authentication_token
 begin
  self.access_token = Devise.friendly_token
 end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
end
```

this is the api call im making
[image]

this is json that im sendng

```
{"email": "bearatamer+testfour@gmail.com", "password": "amer1234"}
```

Comment: Can you show what line of code and what file the error is coming from please?

Comment: Just seen it in your stack trace, can you paste your whole users_controller file? The error is coming from line 46

Comment: @Mark I did update my question.

Answer (score 1):

**If you see the screenshot of console you attached**, you will notice that params are: **`email, password, defaults` and `user`** if you look closely, you will see that this `user` has a hash, which only contains email and no password. **This gives us a hint.**

Now, in your user_params method:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
end
```

Here, **`params.require(:user)` will require a key named `user` to be present**, which is present, otherwise error will be thrown. Next you have: `.permit(:email, :password)` which permits these two params in parent `user` key's hash value.

Now, it seems like some issue in the JSON being sent, either you didn't posted complete json or something is transforming your json before sending, or before handling it to controller(which is highly unlikely if anyone does this kind of customization, but who knows).

Solution: If i were you, i will double check my json, or infact i will send only this json: `{"user": {"email": "bearatamer+testfour@gmail.com", "password": "amer1234"}}` or if you don't want the nesting under `user` key, you must remove `require` from strong params on `user` key.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with this line

```
 if user && user.authenticate(password)
```

once i change to this it worked

```
 if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```